# charAt() giving me bad output

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop

I am making a programming language, and where semicolons are in javascript, slashes are in mine.

Here is the code:

```js
        document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].addEventListener("change", function() {
            var file = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(evt) {
                var lines = [];
                var data = evt.target.result;
                var i;
                var j;
                for (i = 1; i <= data.length; i++) {
                    var search = data.charAt(i);
                    if("/" === search){
                        lines.push(i);
                    }
                }
                document.body.innerText = lines.toString();
            };
            reader.readAsText(file, "UTF-8");
        }, false);
```

```html
<body>
    <input type="file">
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
```

It should output where the slashes are, but every time I run a file, it tells me the position of the character after the slash.

I know I can use some math to get rid of it, but why is this happening?

Thanks, EthanZoneCoding

Comment: `charAt()` is zero-based. You should start your iteration at 0: `for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {}`. As to that math you're referring to: `i + 1`.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen still same output

Comment: Not possible. Did you do `lines.push(i + 1);`?

Comment: let me try.....

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yes it worked ... sorry

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen can you post you comment as an answer?

Comment: Buddy, its totally working fine for me, i have tried for `.txt` and `.png` file extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first: [`charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) is zero-based, so you should start your iteration at `0` and end before you get to `data.length`:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    /* ... */
}
```

If you want to store one-based indexes instead of zero-based indexes, it suffices to just add `1`:

```
lines.push(i + 1);
```